# Google API - Account disabled and then re-enabled, now "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"

Tags: google-api

We've had an application happily running with OAuth 2 security (service account and a p12 key) for a couple of years, updating Google directory information (i.e. telephone numbers, names, etc.) via the directory API.  The account (i.e. user@domain.com) was mistakenly disabled, so the updates stopped working.  The account has been re-enabled (I have verified this by logging in), but the application is now getting 403 - "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" errors when attempting to perform updates.

I've gone through everything I can think of the in the Google API console, and everything seems okay with the service account.  Can anyone think of something obvious that I should check to figure out the problem?

If it helps any, the Java code used to do the build the authentication is:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(httpTransport)
  .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
  .setServiceAccountId(googleServiceAttributes.getServiceAccountId())
  .setServiceAccountScopes(serviceAccountScopes)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(googleServiceAttributes.getPrivateKey())
  .setServiceAccountUser(googleServiceAttributes.getServiceAccountUsername())
  .build();
```

(the account scope being used is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user", the client jar being used for the directory API is google-api-services-admin-directory_v1-rev22-1.16.0-rc.jar and the API jar is google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same API through 'Try It'.